# Java GUI multiple selection program

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist

I'm having a hard time with GUI.

Basically I want to create a program that can select and add items from a given list and display the total amount(price of the item) from the added items. So, when I add items items from the `leftlist` the price will appear in the `rightlist`, and when I press the `totalbutton`, the total price of the selected items will appear via `JLabel`. Sample would be:

[image]

So far, this is what I've done:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
public class MP2_1 extends JFrame{
private JList leftlist;
private JList rightlist;

private JButton addbutton;
private JButton totalbutton;
private static String[] items = {"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"
, "item6", "item7", "item8", "item9", "item10"};

private JButton total;
public MP2_1()  {
super("MP2_1");
setLayout(new FlowLayout());

leftlist = new JList(items); 
leftlist.setVisibleRowCount(5);
leftlist.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
add(new JScrollPane(leftlist));

    addbutton = new JButton("ADD");
    addbutton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    rightlist.setListData(leftlist.getSelectedValuesList().toArray());
                }
            }
    );
    add(addbutton);


    rightlist = new JList();
    rightlist.setVisibleRowCount(5);
    rightlist.setFixedCellWidth(55);
    rightlist.setFixedCellHeight(20);
    add(new JScrollPane(rightlist));

    totalbutton = new JButton("Total");
    totalbutton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    rightlist.setListData(leftlist.getSelectedValuesList().toArray());
                }
            }
    );
    add(totalbutton);



}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    MP2_1 list = new MP2_1();
    list.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    list.setSize(300,300);
    list.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

I must have made a mistake in the structure like using `setListData` but I can't think of any other way of transferring a price of an item there, right now it only transfers the item itself.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? Where do you add the prices of the items contained in the rightlist? Wouldn't this require a loop of some kind to iterate through the list's model's data? I don't see any use of a loop in your code. Note that you'd likely be better off using the right JList's model rather than adding items to the JList itself.

Comment: Can you please share the class code in which you have item name and its price listed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your above example and found two things. One that it doesn't preserve the previously selected item in the list once we click on Add button to add items to right list. Second thing was that you are using the String to show items in the list but we need to have price also with the list object.

To have price associated with item I have created another class which contains Item Name and also its price which will be used in the List. Below is the Item class, check comment of toString method for correct understanding and usage of it with JList.

```
public class Item {

    private String itemName;
    private Integer itemPrice;

    public Item(){}
    public Item(String itemName, int itemPrice){
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
    }
    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }
    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }
    public Integer getItemPrice() {
        return itemPrice;
    }
    public void setItemPrice(Integer itemPrice) {
        this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
    }
    @Override
    /*
     * This is very important to override as it will be used by JList to show the item name
     */
    public String toString(){
        return this.itemName;
    }
}
```

I have modified your original class to use above Item class which will achieve what you have described in your question. Note that I have used Integer for your Item price you can modify it to have Double also. Also check comments in the code below to understand the changes done in the class.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MP2_1 extends JFrame {
    private JList leftlist;
    private JList rightlist;

    private JButton addbutton;
    private JButton totalbutton;
    private JLabel totalLabel;


    public MP2_1() {

        super("MP2_1");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // preparing item list it might be coming from somewhere else
        List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        itemList.add(new Item("Item 1", 100));
        itemList.add(new Item("Item 2", 400));
        itemList.add(new Item("Item 3", 500));
        itemList.add(new Item("Item 4", 600));
        itemList.add(new Item("Item 5", 800));
        itemList.add(new Item("Item 6", 300));
        itemList.add(new Item("Item 7", 200));
        itemList.add(new Item("Item 8", 300));
        itemList.add(new Item("Item 9", 400));

        leftlist = new JList(itemList.toArray());
        leftlist.setVisibleRowCount(5);
        leftlist
                .setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        add(new JScrollPane(leftlist));

        addbutton = new JButton("ADD");
        addbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                //make sure you preserve the previously selected list items
                int size = rightlist.getModel().getSize();
                Set objects = new LinkedHashSet();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    objects.add(rightlist.getModel().getElementAt(i));
                }
                objects.addAll(Arrays.asList(leftlist.getSelectedValues()));

                rightlist.setListData(objects.toArray());
            }
        });
        add(addbutton);

        rightlist = new JList();
        rightlist.setVisibleRowCount(5);
        rightlist.setFixedCellWidth(55);
        rightlist.setFixedCellHeight(20);
        add(new JScrollPane(rightlist));

        totalbutton = new JButton("Total");
        totalbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                // iterate over item objects and calculate the total
                int size = rightlist.getModel().getSize();
                Integer totalAmount = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    Object obj = leftlist.getModel().getElementAt(i);
                    Item item = (Item) obj;
                    totalAmount += item.getItemPrice();
                }
                //update the total Amount label
                totalLabel.setText("Total Amount : " + totalAmount);
            }
        });
        add(totalbutton);

        totalLabel = new JLabel("Total Amount : ");

        add(totalLabel);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MP2_1 list = new MP2_1();
        list.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        list.setSize(300, 300);
        list.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I have not worked to correct the user interface but its functional enough to describe what you require.

Comment: Thank you I studied it and I finally got what I was missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on **"when I add items items from the leftlist the price will appear in the rightlist"**
I can think of few ways of doing this, I am going to demonstrate it by using ListCellRenderer, Which is giving you much of the customizing.
I have pointed out the Total value , you can use it with the label.

1. Create an Item Object.
2. Create a Custom  ListCellRenderer and use it with the Lists.

package commonfloor;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MP2_1 extends JFrame {

    private JList leftlist;
    private JList rightlist;

    private final JButton addbutton;
    private final JButton totalbutton;

    private static final Item[] items = {new Item("Item 0", 100), new Item("Item 1", 150), new Item("Item 2", 200), new Item("Item 3", 300)};

    private JButton bTotal;

    public MP2_1() {
        super("MP2_1");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        leftlist = new JList(items);

        leftlist.setCellRenderer(new ItemCellRenderer(ItemCellRenderer.ITEM_NAME));
        leftlist.setVisibleRowCount(5);

        leftlist.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        add(new JScrollPane(leftlist));

        addbutton = new JButton("ADD");
        addbutton.addActionListener((ActionEvent event) -> {
            rightlist.setListData(leftlist.getSelectedValuesList().toArray());

        });
        add(addbutton);

        rightlist = new JList();
        rightlist.setCellRenderer(new ItemCellRenderer(ItemCellRenderer.ITEM_PRICE));
        rightlist.setVisibleRowCount(5);
        rightlist.setFixedCellWidth(55);
        rightlist.setFixedCellHeight(20);
        add(new JScrollPane(rightlist));

        totalbutton = new JButton("Total");
        totalbutton.addActionListener((ActionEvent event) -> {
            int total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < rightlist.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
                Item item = (Item) rightlist.getModel().getElementAt(i);
                int itemPrice = item.getItemPrice();
                total += itemPrice;
            }
            System.out.println("Total " + total);
            // set the total label here
        });
        add(totalbutton);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MP2_1 list = new MP2_1();
        list.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        list.setSize(300, 300);
        list.setVisible(true);
    }

}
 //Create an Item Object.  

class Item {

    private final String itemName;
    private final int itemPrice;

    Item(String itemName, int itemPrice) {
        this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public int getItemPrice() {
        return itemPrice;
    }

}
//Create a Custom  CellRenderer and use it with the Lists.

class ItemCellRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer<Object> {

    static int ITEM_NAME = 0;
    static int ITEM_PRICE = 1;
    private final int type;

    public ItemCellRenderer(int type) {
        this.type = type;
        setOpaque(true);

    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list,
            Object value,
            int index,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Item item = (Item) value;
        setText(type == ITEM_NAME ? item.getItemName() : "" + item.getItemPrice());

        Color background;
        Color foreground;

        // check if this cell represents the current DnD drop location
        JList.DropLocation dropLocation = list.getDropLocation();
        if (dropLocation != null
                && !dropLocation.isInsert()
                && dropLocation.getIndex() == index) {

            background = Color.BLUE;
            foreground = Color.WHITE;

            // check if this cell is selected
        } else if (isSelected) {
            background = Color.RED;
            foreground = Color.WHITE;

            // unselected, and not the DnD drop location
        } else {
            background = Color.WHITE;
            foreground = Color.BLACK;
        }

        setBackground(background);
        setForeground(foreground);

        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much your answer is also very useful but I chose the other one because he answered first. Thank you again.